# how to dynamically name the xml while creating xml

Tags: php, html, xml, date, dom

I need to save the XML and dynamically name the each newly created xml according to current date with increment of each new XML.

lets assume if I access the html form today first time and create an XML after submiting the form then the XML Name should be 
**Current Date-001**

> (20161225-001)

and if I create the new XML from accessing the HTML Form then the NExt XML should be saved as

> 20161225-002

and it goes on.

this is my Code.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$xml= new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml->formatOutput=true;
$doc=$xml->createElement("clip");
$xml->appendChild($clip);

$supplier=$xml->createElement("supplier");
$supplier->setAttribute("id",1);
$clip->appendChild($supplier);
//first metadata tag
$metadata=$xml->createElement("metadata");
$clip->appendChild($metadata);
$name=$xml->createElement("name","owner");
$metadata->appendChild($name);
$value=$xml->createElement("value","self");
$metadata->appendChild($value);
echo "<xmp>".$xml->saveXML()."</xmp>";
    $xml->save("company_test.xml") or die("Error,Unable to create");
?>
```

Comment: what/where exactly is the problem? how to save? how to create the date? how to find the last serial number? Please change the code/question and keep **only** whats relevant. I'm 99% sure that the line `$supplier=$xml->createElement("supplier");` is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Hey @Dekel my problem is here I need to save the each time newly created XML and Name of the XML should be current date - 001 and if I create second then 002

Comment: So your question is "how I know what is the name of the last file I created?" ?

Comment: My question is each newly created XML should have dynamic name and naming should be as current date -001

Comment: And something like this 20151225-001.xml 20151225-002.xml 20151225-003.xml

Comment: But your actual question is not related to XML and not to DOM. It's "how I know the last file I created and how to create a new filename with the *next* serial number". Am I correct? It would be the exact same question if it was images/pdf/video files...

Comment: And if the date changes then serial number starts again from 001

Comment: ok, so update the question to that :) your question is not related to HTML/XML/DOM (you can remove them from the tags), and all the PHP code inside your question is also not relevant. Add the code that you think should do the work.

Comment: As much as it is important to write code, it's even more important to know what the problem that you are facing and how to describe it :) Now that you know the problem - you might even be able to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. You must create a file 20161225-1.txt, if this file under a folder give permission 777 to folder

```
<?PHP
$files = glob("*.txt"); //path of txt file
$divi = (explode(".", $files[0]));
//print_r($divi[0]);
$divided = (explode("-", $divi[0]));
//echo $divided[0];
//echo "<br>";
//echo $divided[1];
//echo "<br>";
//echo $files[0];
header();

$current = $divi[0];
$onprocs = date('Ymd');

if($divided[0] == $onprocs) {
    rename($current.".txt", $divided[0] . "-" . ($divided[1] + 1).".txt");
    $newname = $divided[0] . "-" . ($divided[1] + 1);
} else {
//here if current time if not equal to filename reset the file name
    rename($current.".txt", $onprocs . "-1.txt");
    $newname = $onprocs . "-1";
}


$xml = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->formatOutput = TRUE;
$doc = $xml->createElement("clip");
$xml->appendChild($clip);

$supplier = $xml->createElement("supplier");
$supplier->setAttribute("id", 1);
$clip->appendChild($supplier);
//first metadata tag
$metadata = $xml->createElement("metadata");
$clip->appendChild($metadata);
$name = $xml->createElement("name", "owner");
$metadata->appendChild($name);
$value = $xml->createElement("value", "self");
$metadata->appendChild($value);
echo "<xmp>" . $xml->saveXML() . "</xmp>";
$xml->save($newname . ".xml") or die("Error,Unable to create");


?>
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan ; Thank you for your help.i just need to know lets say if i submit the HTML form today first time then the Name of Created XML Should be 20161225-001.xml and if second time then 20161225-002.xml